# Inserting rows at a table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I am trying to add rows at the end of table. For example:

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
Tab=table;
s=struct;
for i=1:5
    s.name=LastName{i};
    s.age=Age(i);
    s.heigt=Height(i);
    s.weight=Weight(i);
    s.BP=BloodPressure(i);
    temp=struct2table(s);
    Tab(end+1,:)=temp;
end
```

The table is declared empty, it adds the 1st row, but in the second iteration of the for loop gives below error message:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch for table variable 'name'.
```

I understand that this happens because of the variable name has more characters in the second iteration. Is there any way to implement this?

This is a sample code I generated to explain my problem. In my actual code, the problem is similar, but a structure type variable is being returned from a different function which I can't modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define the whole structure array:

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
s = struct('name',LastName,'age',num2cell(Age),...
    'heigt',num2cell(Height),...
    'weight',num2cell(Weight),...
    'BP',num2cell(BloodPressure,2));
```

And then convert it to table:

```
Tab = struct2table(s);
```

The result:

```
Tab = 
       name       age    heigt    weight        BP    
    __________    ___    _____    ______    __________
    'Smith'       38     71       176       124     93
    'Johnson'     43     69       163       109     77
    'Williams'    38     64       131       125     83
    'Jones'       40     67       133       117     75
    'Brown'       49     64       119       122     80
```

Comment: You're killing me with all of these loops.... `struct('name', LastName, 'age', Age, 'height', Height, 'weight', Weight, 'BP', BloodPressure)`

Comment: I wasn't sure what the OP 'knows' about the data, but I was just about editing the answer, but you can't take your suggestion as is, it makes the structure nested with all the data

Comment: Good call. Also you may want to tweak `BloodPressure(i,:)` to it grabs both values.

Comment: @Suever would you say those loops are killing you over and over? :p

Comment: @EBH Yes, this solves the problem, actually I have to use your loop based solution due to structure of my code. But now I am more interested on the nature of the problem, i.e. If the values are initialized during creation of the table, they can have different character length, but not when a row is added? any suggestion on that?

Comment: @Boss_Bandor I don't understand your question, but I suggest that you'll ask it in a different post, where you can give an example and clarify your issue.

Comment: @EBH It's not a separate problem, I was just curious about why I can't add a row to a table if the 'variable' has 'dimension' mismatch? In this case which is having more characters in the name column.

Comment: @Boss_Bandor Have you tried this: `Tab.name{end+1} = 'new_name'`?

Comment: @EBH I think it's interesting you have BP a table of 1 x 2 arrays. I really like that feature. When I use writetable(Tab,'output.xlsx') it creates columns labeled BP_1 and BP_2. Interesting, not ideal, but so then I tried using readtable('output.xlsx') and it doesn't interpret the subscripted like columns as elements in an array. Is there a way to make this read/write of this style bidirectional ins excel?

Comment: @AlexanderLaut I don't think that's possible OOB with `readtable` or a similar function. You will have to perform a small manipulation on the table after importing the data. But I must admit I'm not using Matlab for more than four years, so I might be missing some new trick.